# Error while writing to an Azure Worker role Input Endpoint

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles, tcplistener

I'm trying to create an azure application which can recieve messages on a TCP port. I have configured an input endpoint shown below :

Endpoint Name:GPRSEndpoint
Type:Input
Protocol:TCP
Port:10000

My azure worker role code looks like this:-

```
TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.InstanceEndpoints["GPRSEndpoint"].IPEndpoint);
        listener.ExclusiveAddressUse = false;
        listener.Start();

 while (true)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                if (listener.Pending())
                {
                    Trace.WriteLine("Incoming Request", "Information");
                    TcpClient c = listener.AcceptTcpClient();  //waiting for client to connect
                    Stream s = c.GetStream();
                    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);
                    string text = sr.ReadLine();

                    if (text != null && text.Length > 0)
                    {
                        Trace.WriteLine("Saving GPRS Packets into Storage Table", "Information");
                        //Saving GPRS Packets into Storage Table
                        Site site = new Site();
                        site.GPRSPacket = text;
                        var insertOperation = TableOperation.Insert(site);
                        siteTable.Execute(insertOperation);
                    }
                    c.Close();
               }

               Trace.TraceInformation("Working", "Information");
            }
        }
```

And finally my client program looks like this:-

```
TcpClient c = new TcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("\nConnecting to Azure...");

            IPAddress AzureWorkeraddress = IPAddress.Parse("168.63.239.54");
            //String AzureWorkeraddress = "http://clienttcpcloud.cloudapp.net/";
            //IPAddress AzureWorkeraddress = IPAddress.Parse("65.52.184.129");

            c.Connect(AzureWorkeraddress, 10000);  //Azure Worker Role's INPUT TCP Endpoint 168.63.239.54 or (http://clienttcpcloud.cloudapp.net/)
            Console.WriteLine("\n<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<Server Connected>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>\n");

            Console.WriteLine("Sending to Azure...");
            Stream s = c.GetStream();
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(s);
            sw.WriteLine(text);
            sw.Flush();
            Console.WriteLine("\n\nGPRS Packet Sent!!!");

            s.Close();
            c.Close();
```

I've tried changing the port number to several values, but it still fails to respond. The error that i get is:-

```
**A Connection failed because the connecting party did not properly respond after a period of time, or the established connection failed, because connected host failed to respond 168.63.239.54:10000**
```

I really don't know what the problem is.....

Comment: edit-  I changed port and tried changing the deployment cloud service. Still nothing....

Answer (score 0):

There is a sample application at http://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2010/01/17/Creating-an-external-facing-Azure-Worker-Role-endpoint.aspx.  Have you tried that and compared what it is doing to what you are doing?

Comment: I have a  problem with azure as well.  I have used that sample application - most notable is that there is no consuming of or connection to the Worker Role in that sample application.

Comment: I found this tutorial more helpful.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/hh285885?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396